# PHP Syntax error, am I blind?

Tags: php, ajax, syntax, compiler-errors

I got this syntax error saying there is a mistake on line 4, but I can't seem to find it..can you help me?

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in **C:\XAMPP\htdocs\projekt\ajax.php** on line **4**

My code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["key"])) {

    $conn = new mysqli(host:"localhost", username:"root", passwd:"", dbname:"serije_bp");

    $name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["naziv"]);
    $opis = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["opis"]);
    $ocjena = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["ocjena"]);

    if ($_POST["key"] == "dodajNovu") {
        $sql = $conn->query(query: "SELECT id FROM serije WHERE naziv = '$naziv'");
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0)
            exit("TV serija je vec unesena!");
        else {
            $conn->query(query: "INSERT INTO serija (naziv, opis, ocjena)
                                VALUES ('$naziv', '$opis', '$ocjena')");
            exit("TV serija je uspjesno unesena!");
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: read the manual maybe? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: even your query failed http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: what is query: in this line $conn->query(query: "SELECT id FROM serije WHERE naziv = '$naziv'"); .. I don't think you need that

Comment: *"am I blind?"* - Yes because you didn't read any of the manuals and their proper syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Like the documentation says, simply add parameters without “:“. So please remove “host:“ and so on

Comment: this is rather a poor answer

Comment: @Fred-ii- i rather agree

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to connect to db in mysqli would be

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "serije_bp");
```